# <p:messages> does not display validation messages of <p:fileupload>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

on one of my pages, it is possible do open a file upload inside of a dialog. I want possible validation messages from the file upload component to be displayed inside of the dialog. As I understand it, I should be able to customize style and positioning of the validation messages that [<p:fileUpload>](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/fileupload) produces (for example `invalidSizeMessage`) using `<p:messages>` , like this:

```
<h:form id="frmDocUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:dialog header="headtext" id="dlgDocUpload"
              widgetVar="dlgDocUpload" 
              dynamic="true" modal="true" fitViewport="true" resizable="true" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true">
        <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('dlgDocUpload').hide();" />

        <p:fileUpload
                fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}"
                id="fileUploader" widgetVar="fileUploader"
                mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true"
                process="@form" sequential="true"
                oncomplete="PF('dlgDocUpload').hide();"
                sizeLimit="#{bean.documentService.getUploadSizeLimit()}"
                invalidSizeMessage="Size Limit (#{bean.documentService.getUploadSizeLimitMB()} MB)!"
                skinSimple="true" />

        <p:messages for="fileUploader"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

However, when I try that, nothing happens, the validation messages stays at the top right where it's always been. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Perhaps, you can try a fixed size/message instead of retrieving them from your backend to ensure that the problem is not there.

Comment: @ivasanpag Didn't fix the problem unfortunately